How to convert a scientific notation string to normal string
I have a below program which is reading and displaying decimal numbers.
import java.math.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      String valStr = "-5.36870912E+9";
      Object val = null;
      DecimalFormat mDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
      mDecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
      mDecimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(38);
      try {
        val = new BigDecimal(mDecimalFormat.parse(valStr).toString());
        System.out.println("valStr = " + valStr + " val = " + val + " mDecimalFormat.parse(valStr) " + mDecimalFormat.parse(valStr));
      }
      catch (ParseException ee) {
          System.out.println("Caught Exception");
      }
  }
}

It generates a below output.
valStr = -5.36870912E+9 val = -5.36870912 mDecimalFormat.parse(valStr) -5.36870912

Here the issue is, parse ignores the exponential format.
I tried to use below code with BigDecimal and it works fine.
BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal(valStr);
val = new BigDecimal(mDecimalFormat.parse(temp.toPlainString()).toString());
Output with above changes are 
valStr = -5.36870912E+9 val = -5368709120 mDecimalFormat.parse(valStr) -5.36870912

But the problem is, if I try to use inputs from different locale, For example, French as shown below.
String valStr = "-5,36870912E+9";
Ending up with below exception.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Character , is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark.
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:522)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:405)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:838)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)

I have referred various pages, most of the suggestions were to use BigDecimal, Double.
Is there any way i could convert the string "-5,36870912E+9" to "-5368709120" before calling parse method?

Best way to convert Locale specific String to BigDecimal

DecimlaFormat does not accept E+, try String valStr = "-5.36870912E9"

there any way i could convert the string "-5,36870912E+9" to "-5368709120".  What about 5,33E+4?  That could be 5330000 or 53300 depending on locale.  Do you not know the locale(s) for the given value(s)?

"Is there any way ..."--> DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(appropriateLocaleHere).parse(valStr.replace("E+","E"))

@user85421 thank you for the response, as you said, replace logic works for E+, what about E-? For example "1.23E-8" will be represented as 0.0000000123.

@RandomGuy  It supports E- just fine.  So E for positive exponents and E- for negative exponents.

It's a pity DecimalFormat is so inflexible. Since Double.toString() outputs "...E+...", it would have been nice if it parsed it. Also, DecimalFormat doesn't work with Indian locales.

@k314159  DecimalFormat and NumberFormat have been around since  Java 1.1  Perhaps it's long overdue for an update.

maybe you must divide the problem: 1 - parsing a string to number; 2 - representing (formatting) the number as a string

thank you all for the help, issue is solved after using below code.
val = new BigDecimal(mDecimalFormat.parse(valStr.toUppercase().replace("E+", "E").toString());
